# Failing to publish a Windows Forms project

Tags: c#, winforms, publishing

I am trying to click on the project and publish it. But what I get is this:

> ```
> Error 94  An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign
> ```
>
> bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: The signer's
>   certificate is not valid for signing. SignTool Error: An error
>   occurred while attempting to sign:
>   bin\Debug\app.publish\setup.exe  CHATT3R

What does it mean?

Comment: From the error message it looks like that the "signer's certificate is not valid for signing.", make sure certificate is valid.

Comment: How will I make so??!? it creates a temp certificate to my project, but I dont know what it does

Comment: First search hit: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/ea9c799e-719e-4a0b-b89b-ed1abb89c45b/

Answer (score 60):

I had this problem. It turns out the certificate had expired (useful error message - thanks Microsoft)

If you go to the Signing page in the project properties you can see the expiry date, and create a new test certificate if required.

Comment: This worked for me too - but had to restart Visual Studio first though.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Signing page in the project properties and Uncheck Sign The ClickOnce manifests.

[image: Please see screenshot]

Comment: I don't think this is a useful suggestion to not sign manifest...

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I just did:

- Right-click on your project.
- Choose Settings.
- Go to Signing page in.
- Untick "Sign the ClickOnce manifests".

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem problem with signing with an error `error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\....exe. SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred` the interesting thing was that my certificate was **not** expired.

In my case problem was with Timestamp server URL - don't know why, but the previously provided URL by some reason was not working anymore (maybe some temporary unavailability?)

Switched it to different Timestamp server URL and signing was working again
[image]

The Timestamp server URL which was not working
http://tsa.starfieldtech.com

The Timestamp server URL I replaced it with was http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll

Comment: just had this same issue - changed timestamp server URL to the previous one - and problem with signing was gone